# How to select some rows with specific rownames from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with several rows. I want to select some rows with specific rownames (such as `stu2,stu3,stu5,stu9`) from this dataframe. The input example dataframe is as follows:

```
        attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4
  stu1      0     0     1     0
  stu2     -1     1    -1     1
  stu3      1    -1     0    -1
  stu4      1    -1     1    -1
  stu5     -1     1     0     1
  stu6      1    -1     1     0
  stu7     -1    -1    -1     1
  stu8      1    -1     0    -1
  stu9     -1    -1     1    -1
  stu10    -1     1     0     1
```

Expected output:

```
        attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4
  stu2     -1     1    -1     1
  stu3      1    -1     0    -1
  stu5     -1     1     0     1
  stu9     -1    -1     1    -1
```

Comment: In my opinion the question is a valid one. The user has given the expected result. Yes, he seems to be a newbie with a minimal understanding of R but I believe that this shall not be held against him. After all, we are all noobs in some areas.

Comment: `sel = c('stu2', 'stu3', 'stu5', 'stu9')` and 
`df[sel,]`

Comment: I came here because `read.table` automatically converted some names substituting dashes with dots, which I didn't notice. I did not understand why my row selection did not work and wanted to be sure I was not crazy and that I had not just dreamed the `df[sel,]` syntax based on some confusion with pandas. By the way, `check.names = FALSE` in `read.table` was the solution to my troubles.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Assuming that you have a data frame called `students`, you can select individual rows or columns using the bracket syntax, like this:

- `students[1,2]` would select row 1 and column 2, the result here would be a single cell.
- `students[1,]` would select all of row 1, `students[,2]` would select all of column 2.

If you'd like to select multiple rows or columns, use a list of values, like this:

- `students[c(1,3,4),]` would select rows 1, 3 and 4,
- `students[c("stu1", "stu2"),]` would select rows named `stu1` and `stu2`.

Hope I could help.

Comment: if the rows and columns to be extracted are consecutive, then students[<staringRowNo.>:<endRowNo.>, <startColnNo.>:<endColNo.>] can also be used. eg; students[11:20, 2:10] selects rows 11 to 20 and columns 2 to 10. However, if row names or column names have to be specified, then students[c("rowname1", "rowname2", ...), c("colname1", "colname2"..] can be used.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use this:

```
DF[paste0("stu",c(2,3,5,9)), ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
rownames(df) <-  letters[1:10]
df[c('a','b'),]
```