# Extracting rows from data frame based on another data frame

Tags: r, time-series, filtering, subset, datamatrix

I'm trying to extract a set of genes (row names) from my large data set based on another data matrix that contains a list of my genes of interest. I've read about that I should use the filter and %in% command, but am unsure as to how to write it properly.

example: 
my large database:

```
Gene        Week1         Week 2.        Week 3
A.           20.           14.            5
B.           5.            10.            15
C.           2.            4.             6
D.           20.           18.            19
```

my small data base:

```
Gene
A
C
D
```

And I want my result to be:

```
Gene        Week1         Week 2.        Week 3
A.           20.           14.            5
C.           2.            4.             6
D.           20.           18.            19
```

Could anybody please help out? I'd really appreciate it and my apologies for the rather simple question :)

Comment: Did you take a look at this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933187/how-to-select-some-rows-with-specific-rownames-from-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using logical row indexes:

```
large_database[large_database$Gene %in% unique(small_data_base$Gene), ]
```

Explanation:

```
large_database$Gene %in% unique(small_data_base$Gene)
```

Checks for each entry (i.e. row) in `large_database$Gene` if it appears in `unique(small_database$Gene)` i.e. the list of unique values in the column `Gene` of `small_data_base` and returns a boolean vector (a vector of TRUE and FALSE).

We then can use this vector as a row 'index' to selecet only rows where the vector is TRUE (i.e. the value of `large_database$Gene` was in `unique(small_database$Gene)`

Comment: In case `Gene` is in both unique, `match` could be used: `large_database[match(small_data_base$Gene, large_database$Gene),]`

Comment: Actually for `match` or `tidyr::join` etc. to work it would be enough if  `small_data_base$Gene` has only unique values (not both). But since the question asked explicitly for a solution using `%` suggested the solution above ;)